# How does one utilize JSON response data from an AJAX call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, response

I can't seem to execute any code from an AJAX call or utilize the JSON response. What am I missing? The call is successful, and I can see in Firebug that the script executes fine on the server side, but I can't seem to do anything with the data that comes back.

```
review.single = {
    id: null,
    ip: null,
    el: null,
    addFlag: function(){
        if(this.id && foo.user_id){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: '/reviews/add_flag/',
                data: ,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                    if(data.success){
                        this.el.text('Flagged');
                        this.el.css({
                            'text-indent': none,
                            backgroundColor: '#c00',
                            color: '#fff'
                        })
                    } else {
                        $('#growl').text(data.message);
                        $('#growl').fadeIn(500).delay(5000).fadeOut(200);
                    }                   
                }
            })
        }
    }   
}
```

I get this back on one of the calls response types:

```
{success: false, message: "You have already flagged this item."}
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to take the message and throw it into the growl and show it, and use the `success` property as a check.

UPDATE:

I added an `error` block; looks like this:

```
error: function (request, status, error) { 
    alert(request.responseText); 
}
```

As a result, I get an alert that says:

```
{success: false, message: "You have already flagged this item."}
```

Comment: and what happens instead? Also if you very roughly put an `alert(data);` do you get something interesting?

Comment: That's the weird thing: none of the code in the `success` area seems to execute, whether I put an `alert(data)` or `alert('blah')`.

Comment: if nothing happens in `success`, try adding an `error` handler.  Any response will be ignored  by `success` if there is some kind of error.

Comment: Are you sure that your call succeed? your data parameter does not seems to have a correct sintax, maybe `data: {},` would be better...

Comment: Have you tried to add an error block (Ie. `error: function (request, status, error) { alert(request.responseText); }`)? Also, have you checked the requests with Firebug?

Comment: so this means there is some kind of error.  perhaps your JSON format is wrong?  what is the `error` that is passed to the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

My JSON was apparently not formatted correctly, and the properties needed to be wrapped in `"`. This threw an error back to jQuery. Thanks for the help, guys.

Example:

```
{"success": false, "message": "You have already flagged this item."}
```